# Issues running both elevated and non-elevated code in the same script

Tags: function, powershell, elevation

I have a need to run some elevated code in powershell as well as some non-elevated code (to make some user specific changes). I have been able to get the elevation to work but once the code is elevated I cannot not run code in an unelevated state.

Using the sample code block below (which I hijacked from the linked website), I tried turning this into a function and passing the name of another function to the RunAs-Admin function such that it will execute only that block then return. 
I cannot get the code to execute only a single elevated function! No break/exit/etc will return you back to the original code at the user level!

```
#### ========================
#### Self Elevate
#### ------------------------
function RunAs-Admin
{
    Param($elevate)    


    #### ========================
    #### Code credit of Ben Armstrong’s Virtualization Blog
    #### https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/
    #### ========================
    # Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
    $myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

    # Get the security principal for the Administrator role
    $adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

    # Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
    if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
    #### $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    clear-host
    }
    else
    {
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell

    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    ####$newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
    $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
    }
    #### ========================
    #### Elevated Function
    #### ========================

    $(& $elevate)

    Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

    #### ========================
    #### Elevated Function
    #### ========================   
}

function SomeElevatedCode1
{
   #### things happen elevated
}

funtion SomeUserLevelCode1
{
   #### things happen under the user account at user level
}

RunAs-Admin SomeElevatedCode1
SomeUserLevelCode1
RunAs-Admin SomeElevatedCode1
```

The ideal scenario would be the have RunAs-Admin call a function that needed to be elevated then return back to run the rest of the code below. In my scenario, the ordering of elevated and non-elevated tasks is relevant so I would like to be able to control what is run as an administrator and what is run at the user level.

Ex. Create a System Restore point (Elevated), return back, make some changes to the profile (run as the user), Add a scheduled task (Elevated) etc.

Comment: Code for self-elevation usually works like this: check if I'm running elevated, if not re-run the script "as admin" and exit. For what you're trying to do it's far simpler to create individual scripts for each task and invoke the task scripts w/ or w/o elevation from a wrapper script.

Comment: Why not just use a PSSession instead? You can run the script as a standard user, put your code that requires elevation into a script block, and then just run it as a job using credentials that have administrative rights.

Comment: Session is essentially what I'm doing, but it never comes back to the user level so any user level changes happen to the administrator profile not the user profile.

Comment: I had it broken up into a couple files and that worked ok, but I was trying to consolidate everything so it would be more tidy. It's just not working when it's tidy.